# How to change the width of select box

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to change the width of select box in jquery or in html?

Answer (score 7):

In HTML

```
<select name="foo" style="width:30px;">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
</select>
```

In Jquery

```
$('#Id').width(30);
```

Answer (score 6):

use [`css()`](http://jsfiddle.net/X8m4f/1/).

```
$('select').css({'width': 200});
```

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
$('#selectId').width(175);
```